# Level selection logic like a angry birds in coco2d v3.x in ios

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

I'm working with the cocos2d 3.x and Xcode 5.1.1.My game have nine levels,i finished the game logic.i need to fix the level selection screen to my game.this level Screen first level only unlocked other levels are locked,then the first level is completed only the next level to be unlocked otherwise it should be locked(look like the angry birds),help me..

Comment: it seems to me you have a fan club ... upvotes on broad questions like this seem 'orchestrated' to me.

Answer (score 0):

Vague question, what you have to do is save the unlock status. You can use coredata or a database solution, but for something this simple i suggest just using a plist outside the main bundle.